# xubuntu bionic: wrong screen resolution reported

Tags: display

I'm using xubuntu bionic with a 2560x1440 screen.

Everything was ok till last week. Now the xubuntu screen setting reports 2560x1440 resolution, but the actual resolution is lower, it seems to be about 2160x1200: I'm not able to have the full scren resolution.

Any hint?

Comment: The reported resultion is the actual resolution. Perhaps something changed at your monitor meanwhile? And is it a monitor, just a monitor, or a TV? TVs have several modes to account for the overscan/underscan.

Comment: it's a monitor, nothing changed at it. The actual resolution is lower that the reported one.

Comment: Again, not it isn't. But some setting must have changed at the monitor or it's defective.

Comment: Well, observing better I realized it's only in chrome/chromium: they use a devicePixelRatio of 1.2. I don't understand why!!! and how can I reset this value to 1?